# What's the difference between "cien" and "centenar"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I recently read this quote:

> El libro en inglés es como un centenar de páginas más corto.

Why is "un centenar" used here instead of "cien"?  When should we use "centenar" vs. "cien"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the same difference English makes between **twelve** and **a dozen**. Here *como un centenar* means "approximately a hundred".

Comment: ...and many more examples of special words for quantities: Pair=par(2), couple=par(2), ten=decena(10), score=??(20), gross=gruesa(144), thousand=millar(1000) ... See http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/words/intro.htm

Comment: score=veintena(20), ??=treintena(30)